# Fortran 77 arrays to Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am in the process of porting a Fortran 77 code (c. 1990), which was originally written in BASIC (c. 1986) into Python 3 utilizing several modules, namely Numpy and Pandas.

It uses several loops to assign elements of arrays. For instance:

```
6050  do 6100 J = 1,3
         Y(J,1) = Z(J)
6100        continue
```

where Z is a initialized as

```
5000  do 5500 J = 1,3
      Z(J) = 0
5500  continue
```

and Z and Y were allocated memory as

```
dimension C(4), Z(4), ... K(4,4), Y(4,4)
```

Further down the code the Z vector is reassigned after the C vector is constructed using array K

```
6500  do 6600 M = 1,3
         C(M) = (K(M,1)+2*K(M,2)+2*K(M,3)+K(M,4))/6
         Z(M) = Z(M) + C(M)
6600  continue
```

There are several places that this occurs with various other arrays. Z and Y are the most critical arrays, though, as they are how most variables are assigned.

I was wondering how one handles this in numpy? or if there is a better way to attempt this.

currently I have

```
import numpy as np
...
Z = np.zeroes((1,4))
Y = np.zeroes((4,4))
(...etc...)

...
for n in range(1,i) # main loop of calculation
    ...
    Y[0,:] = Z
    ...

    C = (K[:,0]+2*K[:,1]+2*K[:,2]+K[:,3])/6
    Z = Z + C
```

but I dont think this is correct.

I only have a print-out of the source code to go off of. I don't have copies of the input/output files. If I had at least a properly formatted input file, I would retype the fortran into a compiler, run it and see what is happening in the actual code.

Comment: be careful when copying the contents of `Z` into `Y`. If you change `Z` at anytime this will change the values in Y unless you have explicitly used `copy.copy(Z)`.

Comment: @DrBwts I pretty sure this is not true. Changing values in array `Y` with values from array `Z` doesn't make that region of `Y` become a view of `Z`.

Comment: that `for` loop in your Python code has no correspondence in the Fortran code, right?

Comment: The for loop is `6000   do 8500 I = 1, I9 ....`  and has a nested 'do' loop:  `do 6400 L = 1,4`  where most of the 'magic' happens. for instance K is assigned as `do 6200 M = 1,3 K(M,L) = H*D(M,L)` where H is an input variable and D is another 4x4 array. I have handled it in my code as simply `K = H*D`

Comment: Basically the way I understand it, `do 6400 L = 1,4` iterates thru the columns of the vectors.  For instance a variable S is assigned right after the `do 6400 L =1,4` line as `S = Y(3,L)` (several other variables are then assigned, S is passed to a function then a subroutine is called, other functions do some math other subroutines are called, some `if...else..` stuff makes some decisions... then it repeats)

Comment: If your arrays are large, you don't have to initialize them with `zeros`. Since the values are calculated based on other arrays you can use `empty` instead. Also note that your `Z` array has 4 elements but the fortran code loops over only 
three of them, you python loops over all.

Comment: Is simply changing the syntax and using numba or cython isn't an option? This will be most likely the most performant way to port the code. Apart from that, be aware that Fortran uses Column major array order, while the default in Python is row major array order (you have to change the access pattern accordingly)